# Create variable that is named from #{}?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
3.times do |n|
    "project#{n}" = FactoryGirl.create(:project, :title => "Project #{n}")
end
```

That obviously doesn't work... Does anyone know how to make loop where I can make variable name that will change with 'local loop variable' to make a lot of variables like project1, project2, projekt3?

Comment: see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864488/dynamically-creating-local-variables-in-ruby

Comment: What *specifically* are you trying to do? Creating arbitrary variables seems a bit silly, since your source code would either (a) need to change based on the number of factories, or (b) use `send` with dynamically-constructed names all the time. What's the point? **Also**, [Factory Girl has sequences](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences) already and you shouldn't even need to do this manually.

Comment: The best way is to use array and create it by `FactoryGirl.create_list(:project)`.

Comment: I promise you, even if you are *absolutely sure* you need to create variable identifiers dynamically, you are very, very wrong.

Comment: Also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963678/dynamically-set-local-variables-in-ruby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you use Hashes?

```
project = {}
3.times do |n|
    project[n] = FactoryGirl.create(:project, :title => "Project #{n}")
end
```

You get access to the data with `project[1]` ...

Comment: A hash with different key/value pairs is often way easier to work with than the *pile of variables* anti-pattern. In this case even an `Array` would be better since the keys are always numbers.

Comment: and if you want some sugar `project["project#{n}".to_sym] = ....`  then you can access it as project[:project1], project[:project2], etc...

Answer (score 4):

You could use Hashes, as knut suggested, or you can use an array -- since you're starting at 0 and moving consecutively upward.

```
project = Array.new(3)
3.times do |n|
  project[n] = FactoryGirl.create(:project, :title => "Project#{n}")
end
```

Or, more simply:

```
project = []
3.times do |n|
  project << FactoryGirl.create(:project, :title => "Project#{n}")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This provides an illusion of what you're asking...

```
eigenclass = class << self; self; end
3.times do |n|
  eigenclass.class_eval { attr_accessor "project#{n}" }
  eval "self.project#{n} = FactoryGirl.create(:project, :title => \"Project #{n}\")"
end
```

But please don't do this. It's actually creating a property accessor on `Kernel`, one for each value of `n`.

[Here](http://blog.myrecipecart.com/2010/06/ruby-19-dynamic-creation-of-local.html)'s my reference.